# R- vector argument matching and perform corresponding calculation

Tags: r, function, arguments, match

Let's say I want to create a function that takes arguments of value x, y, and type, like

```
myfun <- function(x, y, type=c("all", "add", "multiply", "mean")){
    method <- match.arg(type, several.ok = TRUE)
    * body of the function
}
```

When I call the function by `myfun(10,20, type = "all")`, it will return a table that performs all types of metrics like this

```
method    value
sum         30
multiply    200
mean        15
```

When I call the function by `myfun(10,20, type = c("sum", "multiply"))`, it will return a table like this

```
method    value
sum         30
multiply    200
```

I am wondering how to write a function that can take vector argument, and match the argument to a corresponding calculation, then put the method name and value in a table?

I was thinking about creating a table like the first table above, and then perform subset by matching the first column to the name of the argument. Is is feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can have an attempt using `eval` and `parse` as below. We have to define a custom function for `multiply` as such function is not available.

```
multiply <- function(x, y){
  x*y
}

myfun <- function(x, y, type=c("all", "sum", "multiply", "mean")){
  if("all" %in% type)
  {
    type=c("sum", "multiply", "mean")
  }
  method <- match.arg(type, several.ok = TRUE)
  df<- data.frame(method = character(0), value = double(0))
  #body of the function
  for(m in seq_along(method)){
    df<-rbind(df, data.frame(method=method[m], 
              value=eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s(%f,%f)",method[m],x,y)))))
  }

  df
}
```

**Tests**

```
myfun(2,3)   #like "All"
#    method value
#1      sum     5
#2 multiply     6
#3     mean     2

myfun(12,4, "mean")
#  method value
#1   mean     8

> myfun(12,4, "multiply")
#    method value
#1 multiply    48
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I wonder is there a way to specify argument type = "all", that returns the full matrix? I've tried to code `if (type == c("sum", "multiply","mean"))` and `if (type == "all")` to print partial or full matrix, but it will prompt warning message "condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

Comment: @Helen Glad it worked for you. You can use simple tricks to allow `all` as well. I'll modify my answer in few hours with a way to handle such situation. If you are happy with answer then you can click `tick` in left of answer-box to accept the answer. It will be helpful for future users in that way.

Comment: @Helen I have modified the answer to take care of `"all"`. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful.